# How to display data in MYSQLI using OOP in PHP .

Tags: php, oop, mysqli

Hello stackoverflow ,

SO , I've been trying to display some values in my MYSQLI database using oop in php but unable to do it.

Please how do i do it ?

Thanks

Comment: Like this http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php

Comment: Yes. Can I show you my code ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use *PDO* is apparently the best way to display data from MySQL database using OOP in PHP

```
$stmt = $Connection->prepare("SELECT * FROM countries WHERE name = ?");
$stmt->execute(["name_for_search"]);
$data = $stmt->fetchAll();
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the way to do it simply

```
$searchSql = "SELECT * FROM countries WHERE name = ?";
$Connection = "your mysql connection" ; // ex: in CI : $this->db->conn_id
$stmt = $Connection->prepare($searchSql);
$stmt->bind_param("s", "name_for_search");
$ok = $stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->get_result();
$data = $result->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
```

Comment: this code won't work, due to some specific mysqli limitations.

Comment: Sorry , am using oop not pdo.

Comment: @Adetona 1. this is not PDO either. 2. Yet you should be using PDO anyway.

Comment: ooh! ok. SO , I've been doing it the wrong way  using oop. Thanks I will try this one.

Comment: This is using mysqli and mysqlnd module